# What properties to use admob or Google play account properties?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I just linked my admob account to google analytics (I think it is called universal analytics now). After the linking the system created 2 different accounts  (one based on admob account and the other on my google play account) for the same application. Which one should I use? Does it really matter?

P.D. I did not mentioned it but the accounts are related to an android mobile application.